# Scanning, Checking, Converting, Copying values ... How to ? -- C --

Tags: c, atof

Its been a while now and im still trying to get a certain code to work. I asked some question about different commands etc. before, but now I hope this is the final one (combining all questions in one code).

I basically want to :

*Scan an input (should be character ? )

*Check if its a number

*If not, return error

*Convert that character into a float number

*Copy the value to another variable ( I called it imp here)

Here is what I came up with :

**EDITED CODE***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
main(){  
  int digits;
  float imp=0;
  char* alpha;
  do{

    printf("Enter input\n\n");
    scanf("\n%c",alpha);
    digits=isdigit(alpha);
      if(digits==0){
         printf("error\n\n");
      }
     imp=atof(alpha);
  }while(digits==0);

}
```

The problem is this code does not work at all ... It gives me that atof must be of a const char and whenever I try changing it around, it just keeps failing. I am frustrated and forced to ask here, because I believe I have tried alot and I keep failing, but I wont be relieved until I get it to work xD So I really need your help guys.

Please tell me why isnt this code working, what am I doing wrong ? I am still learning C and really appreciate your help :)

**EDIT**
Error given atm is :

`Argument no 1 of 'isdigit' must be of type 'const int', not '<ptr>char'`

**EDIT**
This code compiles fine, but crashes when an input is entered.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<ctype.h>
  main(){  
  int digits;
  float imp=0;
  char* alpha=0;
  do{

   printf("Enter input\n\n");
   scanf("\n%s",alpha);
   digits=(isdigit(alpha[0]));
   imp=atof(alpha);
  }while(digits==0);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for making it look better sbi, I dont have the editing tools...Not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have scanf do the `atof` conversion for you?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {  
    float imp=0;
    while (1)
    {
       printf("Enter input\n\n");
       if (scanf("%f", &imp) < 1) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your most recent example is failing because `alpha` is a NULL pointer.  Declare it as `char alpha[40];` to allocate space for it.  You'll probably want to use %40s in your format string to prevent `scanf` from overflowing `alpha`.

Also, use `strtod` instead of `atof` and you'll know whether the conversion was successful (better than your method of using `isdigit` which will fail on a negative integer).

Comment: Ahhh thank you very much !!! Your explanation got my code working !!  I had to remove the NULL array as you mentioned, and prevent scanf from overflowing it !!! Legend, thank you:) :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `%s` instead of `%c` and to put it in `char` array (`char*`). You also probably get an error that you need to use `const char*` and not `const char`.

You don't want to read just one character - you want to read an entire string...

**EDIT**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
main(){  
  int digits,i;
  float imp=0;
  char* alpha = malloc(100); /* 100 is for example */
  do{
    printf("Enter input\n\n");
    scanf("\n%s",&alpha);
    for (i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
    {
      if (alpha[i] == '\0')
        break;
      if (!isdigit(alpha[i]))
      {
        printf("error\n\n");
        return ...;
      }
    }
     imp=atof(alpha);
  }while(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I change %s to %c, got less errors. Now I have a new error about digits `Argument no 1 of 'isdigit' must be of type 'const int', not '<ptr>char'`

Comment: I've added an example for something closer to what you probably want.

Comment: Thank you very much for that structure .. I have made mine to compile with no errors .. but it crashes once I input anything, can you please check the edited code ? (see question)

Comment: You need to allocate memory for alpha and give &alpha (address of alpha) instead of alpha when using scanf().

Comment: Thanks for replying .. It says `An object of type '<ptr>void' cannot be assigned to an object of type '<ptr>char'` ...